# cmake can't find boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

My OS is Centos 7,using cmake3 3.17.3,and I use cmake to download a package.When I type

```
cmake3 ..
```

I get

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR filesystem program_options
  system) (Required is at least version "1.50")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
```

However, with

```
rpm -qa|grep
```

I can find

```
boost-filesystem-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64
boost-program-options-1.53.0-28.el7.i686
boost-system-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should install boost-*-devel rpm.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it has been solved